# What format does Xcode use to display 'data' types in plist files?

Tags: xcode, plist

If I open a .plist file in TextEdit, all the properties with type "data" are displayed in Base64 encoding, for example
`<data>SGFja2ludG9zaA==</data>`.

Xcode shows these values in some other format, like
`<54657374 56616c75 65>`.  What is this format called, and how can I convert it to ASCII?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data is just a hex dump of the decoded base64 encoding. To convert to ASCII, look the hex values up in the ASCII table. For your example:

```
54657374 56616c75 65
```

is

```
TestValue
```

A convenient way to get the table is `man ascii` from a terminal prompt.

Comment: it's not Base64, it's just hex dump string of the raw binary data. every two char is a Byte

Comment: @Andy.C Yes. As I said, "a hex dump of the decoded base64 encoding". The base64 is decoded, giving raw binary data, and then dumped as hex for easier consumption by programmers.